# java multithread :The comment section guarantees counter synchronization and why

Tags: java

```
public class CounterThread extends Thread {

        private static int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

                counter++;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            int num = 1000;
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[num];
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                threads[i] = new CounterThread();
                threads[i].start();

// The comment section guarantees counter synchronization and why. .
--------------------------------------------------------------------

                //threads[i].join();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                threads[i].join();
            }
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [All actions in a thread _happen-before_ any other thread successfully returns from a join() on that thread.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

Answer (score 1):

`start()` and immediate `join()` means you execute threads sequentially, not in parallel. Sequential modification of static variable does not introduce concurrent modification issues so code is safe. But it is not "multi-threaded" in common meaning of this term :)

Comment: Sequential execution on different threads without  proper synchronization can still introduce data races. It's that fact that `join` introduces that happens-before relationship that makes this work. A simple delay loop in each thread to ensure that they run sequentially wouldn't.

Comment: Both points are basically correct.  The code above is "serial" not parallel.  But Java still requires happens-before to guarantee writes on separate threads will be seen and the `join` followed by a `start` ensure that.